# Relativelayout inside Scrollview not working

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a relative layout inside a scrollview and I can't get it to work.I tried setting my relative layout's height to wrap_content but it doesn't work also. I can get it to work with linear layout but I don't want to use it for some reason.

Here is my xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="14dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:id="@id/feedback_name"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxHeight="48dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxHeight="48dp"
        android:id="@id/feedback_email"
        android:hint="Your email (optional)"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@id/feedback_name"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@id/feedback_concern"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/feedback_email" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@id/feedback_message"
            android:hint="Message"
            android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="70dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/feedback_concern"
        android:layout_above="@id/feedback_send"
/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Send"
        android:maxHeight="48dp"
        android:id="@id/feedback_send"
        android:background="@color/light"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="error"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:id="@id/errorText"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/feedback_message"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

You can see that the message edittext disappeared when I go to landscape mode and the layout doesn't scroll

Comment: What does not work? What problem are you facing?

Comment: i uploaded the images, the message editext doesn't show on landscape and the layout doesn't scroll

Comment: You need to make a different folder and put your xml files there for what will be shown in Landscape mode. Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I got a scrollable relative layout wokring in my other xmls, this one doesn't. I believe this layout can work in landscape mode, I just need to set it correctly.. If I transfer this xml to landscape folder, it will just show the same

Comment: I wonder, because a Vertical scroll in Portrait is a Horizontal scroll in Landscape.

Comment: create layout-land folder and put you xml layout for landscape in there.

Comment: no, I got it working on my custom dialog without creating a landscape layout and it scrolls correctly. Okay, for this one, ill try the landscape folder..

Comment: I transferred the xml to landscape folder and it doesn't work, it shows the same..

Comment: Here the prob is the dependencies, you mentioned the **send** button as alignBottom so obviously the message will not be appeared in the landscape, solution is the remove alignParentBottom for the **send** and maintain some fixed length for the **edittext**

Comment: I fixed the dependencies and I got it working thanks! however, can't I really use alignParentBottom? because if i don't use it, I will have an extra space below the send button..

Comment: I found that setting the width to fill or match_parent makes all the buttons inside not clickable.  If I change the width in Scrollview to wrap_content then the buttons become clickable inside.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apply the scrollview from top to message edittext.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="14dp" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/feedback_send"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/feedback_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxHeight="48dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/feedback_email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/feedback_name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Your email (optional)"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxHeight="48dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/feedback_concern"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/feedback_email"
            android:minHeight="48dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/feedback_message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/feedback_concern"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:minHeight="70dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@id/feedback_send"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:maxHeight="48dp"
    android:text="Send"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/errorText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="error"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this one doesn't include the send button on the scrollview but it's a better approach for scaling. thanks!

Answer (score 13):

In order to get this down use the following:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    (all your view elements)

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

No need for extra layouts tweeks. :-)

Comment: android:fillViewport="true" in NestedScrollView did the trick for me!

Comment: I have similar problem. Not just it doesn't scrollable, but it only shows single item, I fixed it by: [1] android:fillViewport="true" in scrollview, as this answer suggested [2] use layout_below instead of layout_above in relativelayout child items [3] don't use both layout_alignParentBottom and layout_above at the same time in scrollview.