# RelativeLayout inside Scrollview in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scrollview

I am stuck in a problem and not able find any solution. This problem may sound very naive but I am really unable to figure out the exact cause. I have a ScrollView ans inside that I have a RelativeLayout. But my RelativeLayout is not scrolling irrespective of the content. I have followed https://stackoverflow.com/relativelayout-with-scrollview-not-scrolling and [https://stackoverflow.com/relativelayout-inside-scrollview-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896963/relativelayout-inside-scrollview-not-working) and few more also. Please check where I am doing wrong. Thanks.

**xml code :**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/cover_image"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cover_img_labels"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cover_image_labels"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cover_img_labels"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_login_userName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
                android:textColor="#7593B0"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:hint="@string/hint_login_user" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_login_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/et_login_userName"
                android:textColor="#7593B0"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/hint_login_password"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_login_submit"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_login_submit"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/et_login_password" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_register_submit"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Register your card" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pb_login_progressbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Forgot Password"
                android:id="@+id/bt_forgot_password"
                android:textColor="@color/pink"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/forgot_button_drawable"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bt_forgot_password"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/lll"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It's not like I didn't tried. I tried a lot then I asked. So if you can help me then you are most welcome and if you can suggest some other way for this also it will be good enough for me. And I  already mentioned the links above which I referred. Then why it is not useful down vote.

Answer (score 0):

I just run your code, it cannot scroll because height of relative layout not enough. You only scroll when height of ScrollView smaller than height of ScrollView's child.

You can change RelativeLayout's height from wrap_content to 1000dp to test scroll.

Comment: But I don't want to scroll in all devices. I just want it in small screen devices

Comment: I just run your app in small device (3.7''), but RelativeView's height not greater than screen height (in that case, screen height equals ScrollView's height) so you can not scroll.