# A relative layout inside of a scrollview isn't scrollable

Tags: android, user-interface

Im trying to make a UI with a few fields in the middle of the screen and a button at the bottom. When i am writing a number in the fields, the keyboard hides part of the interface (which i want it to), but i also need the whole interface to be scrollable so that i can adjust the screen and keep filling the fields with the keyboard on. I've put the whole setup in a relative layout and put it under a scroll view. The posts here say it should work that way but it isnt working for me.

The XML code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.maaz.rakattracker.MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/farzET"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="0"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/farzLbl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:text="farz"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/sunnatET"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="0"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sunnatLbl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:text="Sunnat"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/naflET"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="0"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/naflLbl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:text="Nafl"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/witrET"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="0"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/witrLbl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:text="Witr"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Kindly help me figure out the issue here.
Thanks

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in your Activity inside onCreate() method :

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

Comment: thats there. Should i remove the scroll view if that mode is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your Activity tag.

Answer (score 0):

On your manifest file add

```
<activity
        android:name=".YOURACTIVITY"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
```

Comment: thats there. Do i need to remove scroll view and keep it simple with it?

Answer (score 0):

that because scroll view work only with LinearLayout

Comment: no Unfortunately you can not do it.
try to put your relative layout inside linear layout and it will work

Comment: please see scroll android api :
[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)
and for some  techniques see :
[link](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-behavior)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896963/relativelayout-inside-scrollview-not-working   this link shows that it can be done.

Comment: mmm ok from your link you'r missing this 
`android:layout_above="@+id/feedback_send"` and what i think he put it on top of EditText , now try to put it on top of first linear layout or what ever you want , hope it work for you.
and can i know what error did you get when you try the first solution